# Harvest power from an electric fence

Tags: high-voltage, battery-charging

Many farms use electric fences to discourage animals breaking through to neighbouring paddocks.

These electric fences have regular (say once per second) high-voltage spikes of between around 100 V and 120 kV.

Would it be possible to "harvest" this as a power supply for remotely-deployed electronics? e.g. a coil wrapped round the electric fence wire, with a high resistance to ground, trickle-charging a battery.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: I assume you have the ability to turn off the fence to make modifications?  It could be... difficult otherwise.

Comment: 100V and 120KV are very different numbers.  You should probably narrow that range down a bit.   I think that the voltage on these is usually between 2.5kV and 10kV, with pulse durations as short as 10 microseconds.  An interesting problem!

Comment: That's useful info, thanks. I wasn't sure what voltage they actually used, so took the 100V and 12kV numbers from the range of a meter used to test the fences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try connecting a small transformer (one designed for a flyback power-supply) with a high step-down ratio between the energized cable and ground, you could then rectify the output and do whatever with it.  The HV coil impedance should be high enough to avoid a tremendous draw on the cattle killer, but I don't know much about them.  It may take a long while to charge a battery, but possible.  If you just want to power a sensor, I'd use a capacitor.

Comment: It's a cattle fence, not cattle killer.

Comment: That can be fixed if you charge up a big enough array of capacitors ... :P (edit: for the record, I am not advocating cattle murder)

Answer (score 4):

Those fence chargers usually generate a high voltage spike on the wire fence, relative to ground. The wire fence is on insulators to make sure that almost no current flows, unless something touches it. I've heard that wet grass leaning on them can draw enough current to effectively neutralize such a fence.

So here's the take-away: there isn't so much a current *through* the wire as there is a voltage *on* the wire (capacitive charging currents neglected). So if you connected one end of the high-voltage side of a flyback transformer to the fence, and the other end of same winding to ground, you ought to be able to pick off slugs of current on the low-voltage side of the transformer, at a reduced voltage.

Caveat if you try this with a flyback liberated from an old CRT: they often embed a diode in series with the HV winding in those units, and they're usually potted, too.

Comment: If it rains or your grass starts to approach the bottom wire, you can to turn up the voltage on the fence so it kills the grass. There is a significant amount of current available.  But yes, if you let your grass get very tall and then it rains, you'll probably have to bring out the string trimmer and cut it manually.

Comment: Better fence chargers use current monitoring to compensate for this.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly.

I live on a small horse farm and recently made a fence tester using a resistor and a small neon bulb. Even with 10k resistor, I get a really bright flash from the bulb: clearly visible in broad daylight.

The thing I'd want to be careful with is how you get power off the line: intuition says wrap a few turns of insulate wire around it, but that will make a step up transformer and give even more voltage.

If I get a chance tonight I'll try to see if I can power an LED with a single turn around the fence's hot wire.

Comment: A few turns of insulate (sic) wire will give you a capacitive pickoff, not a step up transformer.

Answer (score 0):

We did this about 22 years ago ,when solar cells were much more expensive and less efficient .The unit was birdsnested and bench tested using a middle of the road fence energiser.It did trickle charge a 12V SLA battery.The reasoning was that 10J was typical for an electric fence and they beat at roughly 1 pulse per second .This implies that you could harvest say up to 1 watt without dropping the fence peak volts too much .I used a transformer out of a dead electric fence backwards.There were some power electronic components between the transformer low voltage winding and the battery but nothing expensive exotic or tricky .The bench tests implied good grounding which is not unreasonable because many electric fences have the bottom wire grounded anyway.This never went into production because there was not sufficient demand at the time.